# PHP class - return object but echo string

Tags: php, class

I have a class `CalculatePrice`. Running this code:

```
$calc = new CalculatePrice( 10, 20 );
print_r ( $calc->do() );
```

The `do()` method returns a different class called `PriceObj`. If I ran the code `echo $calc->do()` then I get an error: **Object of class PriceObj could not be converted to string**.

My question is: how can I still return an object from the `do()` method but when running an echo to it, it returns a string or even simpler; true or false? Is this possible?

Comment: Can you post the code.?

Comment: Simply write `return $calc->do()` and in your code echo that desired property or call one of its functions (and that one will `echo` what you want)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's possible when the object is convertible to a string using the [__toString](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring)()-method:

```
class A {
    private $val;

    public function __construct($myVal) {
       $this->val = $myVal;
    }

    public function __toString() {
       return "I hold ".$this->val;
    }
}

$obj = new A(4);
echo $obj; // will print 'I hold 4';
```

Comment: Brilliant. Didn't know about this magic method - thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can only echo strings. But luckily you can convert your object to a string. This can be done automatically by providing a `__toString()` function

This is a magic method that does exactly what you want: make a string out of an object. See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring

The basic thing is you are the only one who knows HOW to make a string from the object (show all or a part of the variables inside for instance), so you need to implement how the string is build yourself.

Comment: I've now implemented this and it works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Implement the magic method `__toString()` on your `PriceObj`.

So:

```
public function __toString()
{
    echo $this->result; // The calculated price
}
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php